# Least rude way of testing if internet (google, aws, etc) is accessible

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, offlineapps

I'm looking for a URL I can use to test if the internet is up.

I can test *my* server with a 1x1 pixel (recommended below), but how to I test if the internet is up, but my server is down.

In my app, I can use these two events about the local network interface (wifi AP), but not the internet (gateway, dns, upstream network):

```
window.addEventListener('online', onNetworkUp, false);
window.addEventListener('offline', onNetworkDown, false);
```

So, I can be "online", but not connected to the internet.

To test "internet", I can ping my API server, but also want to check somewhere else who may have a better SLA.  E.g. google, amazon, etc.

What's the least rude way to do this?  Is there a URL that expects to be used this way?

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found.  There isn't a good way to get this info from the browser.  Browsers overload "online" to make the implementations meaningless.

My use case is this:  I want to know if the app can reach my server, and offer different behavior if it can't.

I had two ways to do this.

- For PouchDB replication, look for failures, and assume offline it's failing - restart as necessary.  I imagine socket.io has a similar feature.
- When I'm not PouchDB replicating, but wanting to demonstrate the offline-ness of the app, I added a route to my Express server /r_u_up and polled with this library [offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)

A last note is /r_u_up could be implemented server-side in Nginx so it doesn't even need Node.js.  I haven't implemented this yet, but the approach would be similar to [enabling the pre-flight OPTIONS requests](http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html).  It should also [work with other web servers](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).

That's what I learn-inated!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check if you are connected to the internet is using `navigator.onLine`:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
    // you are online... do something
} else {
    // you're not online
}
```

However this will not work for your local server, so my second favourite way (since that there are many ways of doing this) is to use any web request, (e.g. an image) adding an `onerror` event:

```
<img src='http://www.example.com/singlepixel.gif' onerror='offline();' />
<script>
    function offline() {
        alert('Internet offline!');
    }
</script>
```

Obviously you should make a request to a little image, `1x1px` for example, so that when you're connected to the internet this doesn't take too long to load.

Or if you want to use pure Javascript:

```
function internetON() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.example.com/singlepixel.gif', false);
    xhr.send();
    return xhr.status === 200;
}

if (internetON()) {
    // you are online... do something
} else {
    // you're not online
}
```

Comment: Hi Marco, when my ISP was down, navigator.onLine was true, but google.com was 404.  Other that checking https://www.google.com is there a better way?

Comment: @MichaelCole 404 doesn't mean offline.. it means "not found". By the way just make an XMLHttpRequest to either google or another site. The best way to do it is by requesting a 1x1 pixel image, that's very fast to load.

Comment: ok, cool.  I was looking for such a URL.  A url of a 1x1 image would be great!

Comment: @MichaelCole You can get a 1px image here http://www.1x1px.me/, and then upload it to your server to use it for the XHR

Comment: great.  I can put that on my server.  The question is has Google or Amazon done this, and if so, what's the URL?

Comment: @MichaelCole there aren't any "official" 1x1 gifs, I'm sorry